# Duplicate Question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Not so long ago I asked this question, where I asked how to make a footer, make it responsive and set its color:

[Color and other footer's parameters in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634673/color-and-other-footers-parameters-in-liferay)

But in the dialog with Parkash Kumar I came to another interesting question: how to make sticky footer in Liferay and decided to create a new topic:

[Sticky footer in Liferay 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641001/sticky-footer-in-liferay-6-2)

So why it's a duplicate? There is a sharp and decisive break between responsive and sticky footers.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see anything related to anything being closed as a duplicate. Are you referring to the **possible** duplicate link flag? Possible meaning: not for certain ?

Comment: @Gimby I'm talking about that light orange frame "This question may already have an answer here:"

Comment: I think only you see that orange box :) Its an attempt to help, but that attempt may be flawed if the person flagging did not read closely enough. It happens.

Comment: "This question **may** already have an answer here" where "may" means: expressing possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just *one* user marking the question as a duplicate; unless that user happens to have a gold badge in one of the question's tags, or the user is a diamond moderator, it is just a close *vote*. Five of those are needed to actually close the question.

The "This question may already have an answer here" banner might be annoying, but if the question does not accumulate any more close votes, the vote will age away and the banner will [disappear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175795/295232) - depending on the number of views on the question, it will take [4 to 14 days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).